# How to test a method which returns data from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, sinon

I have created a new API endpoint in API Gateway mapped my AWS Lambda function and want to write test cases for the JavaScript method which handles requests made to the endpoint. The method creates a connection to AWS DynamoDB using the **aws-sdk** node module to save passed values to the database and returns a `Promise` with relevant data. I do not want the *spec* to trigger a call to the actual DynamoDB or create a new entry to it. I tried using a stub, but it still gave me an error stating that the test-case failed.

Handler.js:

```js
saveUser(userName, logger) {
  const Item = {
    id: uuid.v4(),
    userName,
    ttl: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 900 // expire the name after 15 minutes from now
  };
  const params = {
    TableName: "my-table-name"
  };
  logger.log(`Saving new user name to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.put(params, function(err, _) {
      if (err) {
        logger.exception(`Unable to connect to DynamoDB to create: ${err}`);
        reject({
          statusCode: 404,
          err
        });
      } else {
        logger.log(`Saved data to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(Item)}`);
        resolve({
          statusCode: 201,
          body: Item
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Handler.spec.js:

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10"
});

describe("user-name-handler", function() {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  afterEach(() => sandbox.restore());

  it("Test saveUser() method", async function(done) {
    const {
      saveUser
    } = userHandler;

    sandbox.stub(db, "put")
      .returns(new Promise((resolve, _) => resolve({
        statusCode: 200
      })));

    try {
      const result = await saveUser("Sample User", {
        log: () => {},
        exception: () => {}
      });

      expect(result).to.be.equal({
        data: "some data"
      });
      done();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      done();
    }
  });
});
```

Error:

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

Comment: what's `saveToken` ?

Comment: I mean, `saveUser`.

Comment: Note that all the JS SDK v2 API requests can return [promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `function(done)` with `function()` and remove all the calls to `done()`;

Comment: I removed the `done()` and it passed, but it only covered the branch where the Promise went into error state and rejected. I think it made an actual request to the API, instead of mocking it with the stub.

Comment: @deekeh if you have a problem with the mock - that's a totally different question. Please post a new question with the relevant details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76193901/mocking-a-connection-call-to-aws-dynamodb-in-sinon