# Mocking a connection call to AWS DynamoDB in sinon

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, sinon

I have an endpoint in API Gateway which is mapped to a Lambda function in AWS. While writing test cases for the new handler function of the endpoint, I do not want the *spec* file to call the actual API or connect to DynamoDB. I tried to add a `sinon.stub`, but it still made the call to connect to DynamoDB and the test-case failed. I am unable to locate where the stub went wrong.

Handler.js:

```js
saveUser(userName, logger) {
  const Item = {
    id: uuid.v4(),
    userName,
    ttl: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 900 // expire the name after 15 minutes from now
  };
  const params = {
    TableName: "my-table-name",
    Item
  };
  logger.log(`Saving new user name to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.put(params, function(err, _) {
      if (err) {
        logger.exception(`Unable to connect to DynamoDB to create: ${err}`);
        reject({
          statusCode: 404,
          err
        });
      } else {
        logger.log(`Saved data to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(Item)}`);
        resolve({
          statusCode: 201,
          body: Item
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Handler.spec.js:

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10"
});

describe("user-name-handler", function() {
  const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  afterEach(() => sandbox.restore());

  it("Test saveUser() method", async function(done) {
    const {
      saveUser
    } = userHandler;

    sandbox.stub(db, "put")
      .returns(new Promise((resolve, _) => resolve({
        statusCode: 200
      })));

    try {
      const result = await saveUser("Sample User", {
        log: () => {},
        exception: () => {}
      });

      expect(result).to.be.equal({
        data: "some data"
      });
      done();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      done();
    }
  });
});
```

Error:

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

---

I console-logged the `err` object and it gave me this error, which made me think it is trying to connect to the DynamoDB.

```
Error: connect ENETUNREACH 127.0.0.1:80
  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
message: 'Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1',       
errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
code: 'CredentialsError',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 80,
time: 2023-05-07T10:45:25.835Z,
originalError: {
  message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
  errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  time: 2023-05-07T10:45:25.835Z,
  originalError: [Object]
}
```

---

Related: [How to test a method which returns data from AWS DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76192814/how-to-test-a-method-which-returns-data-from-aws-dynamodb)

Comment: Is this any different to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76192814/how-to-test-a-method-which-returns-data-from-aws-dynamodb)?

Comment: The "done" part was already solved in the previous post - there's no need to repeat it. Please focus this question only on the new problem: why the stub doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Separating the DB connection in a file

We can separate the DB connection in a different file and import it in the handler implementation as well as in the *spec* file.

**db.js**

```js
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

export default db;
```

## The `yields()` function

Instead of the stub directly return a `Promise`, it should be chained with a `.yields()` along with the parameters its callback will accept. We can change the parameters to cover various branches of the code.

## Code

```js
describe("user-handler connection success", function () {
    const sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    afterEach(() => sandbox.restore());
    before(() => {
        sinon.stub(db, "put")
            .yields(null, true);
        sinon.stub(db, "get")
            .yields(null, { sampleKey: "sample value" });
        sinon.stub(db, "delete")
            .yields(null, { sampleKey: "sample value" });
    });
    after(() => {
        db.put.restore();
        db.get.restore();
        db.delete.restore();
    });

    it("Test saveUser() method success", async function () {
        const result = await userHandler.saveToken("sample user", {
            log: () => {},
            exception: () => {}
        });

        expect(result.statusCode).to.be.equal(201);
    });
});
```

## Useful Link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXDbmrh0xDQ

Comment: This answer is misleading: `yields` cannot help you when you're stubbing the wrong instance of `db`. For more details, see my answer above.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I will research some more and then maybe delete this and accept your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are mocking the `db` that is declared in the test file - not the `db` that  `saveUser` is actually using.

The solution is to move the db declaration to its own module, say: db.js

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  apiVersion: "2012-08-10"
});

module.exports = db;
```

and then import it both from the module of `saveUser` and from the test - so that we'll be mocking the same `db` instance that `saveUser` uses.

**UPDATE**

I was able to run the test with the following code successfully:

The test code:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { saveUser } = require('../userHandler');
const { expect } = require('chai');

const db = require('../db');

describe('user-name-handler', function() {
  afterEach(() => sinon.restore());

  it('Test saveUser() method', async function() {

      sinon.stub(db, 'put')
        .returns(new Promise((resolve, _) => resolve({
            statusCode: 201,
            body: 'some data'
      })));

      try {
          const result = await saveUser(db, 'Sample User', {
            log: () => {},
            exception: () => {}
          });

          expect(result).to.deep.equal({
            statusCode: 201,
            body: 'some data'
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
  });
});
```

userHandler file:

```
const db = require('./db');

const saveUser = (db, userName, logger) => {
  const Item = {
    id: uuid.v4(),
    userName,
    ttl: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 900 // expire the name after 15 minutes from now
  };
  const params = {
    TableName: "my-table-name"
  };
  logger.log(`Saving new user name to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(params)}`);

    return db.put(params, function(err, _) {
      if (err) {
        logger.exception(`Unable to connect to DynamoDB to create: ${err}`);
        return reject({
          statusCode: 404,
          err
        });
      } else {
        logger.log(`Saved data to DynamoDB: ${JSON.stringify(Item)}`);
        return resolve({
          statusCode: 201,
          body: Item
        });
      }
    });
}

module.exports = { saveUser };
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "play",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --timeout 5000"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1373.0",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "sinon": "^15.0.4"
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But, removing the done calls and moving the db connection to a separate file & importing separately gives a timeout error `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\path\to\project\specs\handler.spec.js)`. This must be because it is still making the connection call.

Comment: @deekeh I ran it locally and it passed, there was a small change I did in the test (using `sinon.stub` instead of `sandbox`) - I added all the files to the answer so you'll be able to compare.

Comment: `.yields()` did the trick.

Comment: @deekeh yields won't help when you're stubbing the wrong bd instance...

Comment: Stubbing the right db instance along with yields() resolved it.

Comment: Stubbing the right instance solves it. Then you can choose if you want to use `yields` or `returns` - both work.